# Updating react-wavesurfer Region programmatically with State Change

Tags: reactjs, wavesurfer.js

I am having trouble provoking a re-rendering of the regions when the props change.  Here is a simple example:

```
var React = require('react');
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import WaveSurfer from 'react-wavesurfer';
window.WaveSurfer = require('wavesurfer.js');
let Regions = require('./Regions').default;

class SongCard extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      playing: false,
      pos: 0,
      regions: {
        eoi: {
          id: 'eoi',
          start: 5,
          end: 6
        }
      }
    };
    this.togglePlay = this.togglePlay.bind(this);
    this.handleTogglePlayClick = this.handleTogglePlayClick.bind(this);
    this.handlePosChange = this.handlePosChange.bind(this);
    this.handleMoveRegionsClick = this.handleMoveRegionsClick.bind(this);
  }
  togglePlay() {
    this.setState({
      playing: !this.state.playing
    });
  }
  handleTogglePlayClick() {
    this.togglePlay();
  }
  handlePosChange({ wavesurfer, originalArgs}) {
    this.setState({
      pos: originalArgs[0]
    })
  }
  handleMoveRegionsClick() {
    const newState = Object.assign({}, this.state, {
      regions: {
        eoi: {
          start: this.state.regions.eoi.start+10,
          end: this.state.regions.eoi.end+10,
          id: 'eoi'
        }
      }
    });
    this.setState(newState);
  }
  render () {
    return (
        <div>
          <div>
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary btn-xs" onClick={this.handleMoveRegionsClick}>Change Region</button>
          </div>
          <WaveSurfer
            audioFile={'https://ia902606.us.archive.org/35/items/shortpoetry_047_librivox/song_cjrg_teasdale_64kb.mp3'}
            pos={this.state.pos}
            onPosChange={this.handlePosChange}
            playing={this.state.playing}
          >
            <Regions regions={this.state.regions} />
          </WaveSurfer>
        </div>
      );
  }
};


export default SongCard;
```

When I call setState() within handleMoveRegionsClick(), SongCard's state is updated, but it does not trigger a reload of the Region's props.

Could anyone point me in the right direction for how to solve this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this helps someone: It turns out that wavesurfer.js overrides shouldComponentRender() to false, which stops the regions from moving.  For now, I had to fork react-wavesurfer and remove the override.

Comment: v0.8.5 was released and fixes the issue.